# How to change time format using momentjs?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So I want to change time 06:00:00 to 06:00 pm .I heard momentjs is a great library for date and time formatter.
But I am not able to figure out how to use it. can anyone give me a hint on that

Comment: Well, there is differents ways to use it, depending of what you're actually doin' : are you using Node.JS or just a browser-side JS script ?

Comment: I am using nodejs, so I am getting the date in forma t06:00:00 I just want to to format it into format 06:00 pm and display on UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this. I have showed the output in a div.

```
var momentObj = moment("13:15", ["HH:mm"])
document.getElementById("output").innerText = momentObj.format("h:mm A");
```

I have created a fiddle. have a look.

https://jsfiddle.net/Refatrafi/f1y15mqg/

Answer (score 2):

**For Node JS :**
Use NPM :

```
npm install moment
```

Then in your app.js :

```
var moment = require('moment');
moment().format();
```

**Or if you're browser-side only, add in your page :**

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script>
    moment().format();
</script>
```

Then use the format() method to apply your format as described in :
[format() | moment.js docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

EDIT :
for your format (ex : 6:00 PM) the code is :

```
moment().format("h:mm a");
// OR (depending of the needed caps lock for "AM/PM"
moment().format("h:mm A");
```

EDIT 2 :
To format your time, do something like :

```
var currentDate = moment.now();
var formatDate = moment(currentDate).format('h:mm A');
```

Comment: where do I pass my time - 06:00:00 in moment().format();

Comment: @scripter, I add the time passing method at the end of my answer

Comment: Aethyn thanks a lot. What if I get that time from server? Just thr 06:00:00 then? How do I format it?

Comment: How do you get the time from server ? With a Date() object ? If you're using a "var date = new Date()", just pass the date var into the moment().format() object like : moment(date).format('h:mm a');